# drag and drop jquery remove Issue

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have implemented this Drag and Drop: http://hayageek.com/drag-and-drop-file-upload-jquery/.

It works fine, BUT, my issue is the following:

I add a file, then i remove it. When I add another file the "removed" file it appears again but without remove button...

I am desperate to solve this.

I think the issue is or in the handler or in the delete function. But I can't find it. Maybe I need a rest...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#errorMessages").hide();
// Handle drag and drop events with jQuery
var obj = $("#dragandrophandler");
obj.on('dragenter', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid #0B85A1');
});
obj.on('dragover', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
obj.on('drop', function (e) {
    $(this).css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    cleanErrorMessages();
    //We need to send dropped files to Server
    handleFileUpload(files, obj, uploadURL);
});

// If the files are dropped outside the div, file is opened in the browser window. To avoid that we can prevent ‘drop’ event on document.
$(document).on('dragenter', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).on('dragover', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    obj.css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
});
$(document).on('drop', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#file").change(function () {
    cleanErrorMessages();
});

// add file to the list using the input
$("#addFile").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var files = $("#file")[0].files;
    handleFileUpload(files, obj);
    $("#file").val("");
    return false;
});
```

});

There is more code, but I think the issue must be in this part. If I find the solution I will post it aswell.

The remove function:

```
this.remove.click(function (evt) {
    // TO DO:  call to the WS to remove from the server 
    var numrow = evt.currentTarget.parentElement.attributes[1].value;
        evt.currentTarget.parentElement.removeChild(evt.currentTarget);
    $(".statusbar[numrow='" + numrow + "']").fadeOut(1000, "easeInOutCubic", function (evt) {
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, sorry, I edit the post

Comment: I added the remove function, maybe that is the issue, im trying out things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the remove function:

```
this.remove.click(function (evt) {
    // TO DO:  call to the WS to remove from the server 
    var numrow = evt.currentTarget.parentElement.attributes[1].value;
        evt.currentTarget.parentElement.remove(evt.currentTarget);
    $(".statusbar[numrow='" + numrow + "']").fadeOut(1000, "easeInOutCubic", function (evt) {
    });
});
```

Just had to change: `evt.currentTarget.parentElement.removeChild(evt.currentTarget);`  for this: `evt.currentTarget.parentElement.remove(evt.currentTarget);`.